# Avoid repeated checks in loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance

I'm sorry if this has been asked before. It probably has, but I just have not been able to find it. On with the question:

I often have loops which are initialized with certain conditions that affect or (de)activate certain behaviors inside them, but do not drastically change the general loop logic. These conditions do not change through the loop's operation, but have to be checked every iteration anyways. Is there a way to optimized said loop in a pythonic way to avoid doing the same check every single time? I understand this would be a compiler's job in any compiled language, but there ain't no compiler here.

Now, for a specific example, imagine I have a function that parses a CSV file with a format somewhat like this, where you do not know in advance the columns that will be present on it:

```
COL_A,COL_B,COL_F,COL_H,COL_M,COL_T,COL_Z
1,2,3,4,5,6,7
8,9,10,11,12,13,14
...
```

And you have this function to manually process the file (I know there are better ways to deal with CSVs, the question is about optimizing the loop, not about CSV processing). For one reason or another, columns `COL_C`, `COL_D`, `COL_M` and `COL_N` (to name a few) need special processing. This would result in something like:

```
def process_csv(file):
    with open(file, 'r') as f:
        headers = f.readline().split(',')
        has_C = "COL_C" in headers
        has_D = "COL_D" in headers
        has_M = "COL_M" in headers
        has_N = "COL_N" in headers
        
        for line in f:
            elements = line.split(',')
            if has_C:
                ...  # Special processing related to COL_C
            if has_D:
                ...  # Special processing related to COL_D
            if has_M:
                ...  # Special processing related to COL_M
            if has_N:
                ...  # Special processing related to COL_N
            ...  # General processing, common to all iterations
```

As I said above, any way to factor out the checks in some way? It may not represent a noticeable impact for this example, but if you have 50 special conditions inside the loop, you end up doing 50 'unnecessary' checks for every single iteration.

--------------- EDIT ------------------

As another example of what I would be looking for, this is (very) evil code that optimizes the loop by not doing any check in it, but instead constructing the very loop itself according to the starting conditions. I suppose for a (VERY) long loop with MANY conditions, this solution may eventually be faster. This depends on how exec is handled, though, which I am not sure since I find it something to avoid...

```
def new_process_csv(file):
    with open(file, 'r') as f:
        headers = f.readline().split(',')
        code = \
f'''
for line in f:
    elements = line.split(',')
    {... if "COL_C" in headers else ''}
    {... if "COL_D" in headers else ''}
    {... if "COL_M" in headers else ''}
    {... if "COL_N" in headers else ''}
    ...  # General processing   
'''
        exec(code)
```

Comment: If you have to open the file to decide if the check is needed, then the check is runtime by definition, even a compiled language could not deal with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `special processing` can be refactored out to specific functions, eg `f_C()`, `f_D()` etc, then you could make a collection of these functions:

```py
        has_C = "COL_C" in headers
        has_D = "COL_D" in headers
        has_M = "COL_M" in headers
        has_N = "COL_N" in headers

        functions = [(f_C,has_C), (f_D,has_D), (f_M,has_M), (f_N,has_N)]
        functions = [ff[0] for ff in functions if ff[1]]

        for line in f:
            elements = line.split(',')

            for ff in functions:
                ff()    # although I assume that elements will need to be passed in

        ...  # General processing, common to all iterations
```

This means that the tests are done once per call to `process_csv()` rather than every time through the `for` loop.

Comment: This is definitely more in line with what I was looking for, thanks! Definitely a better option than the 'optimized' solution that I just edited into the question. I'm guessing a nested loop is the best that can be done in this regard...? I also wonder how many checks would end up having a nested loop be faster, probably hundreds or thousands haha

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems right to me, performance-wise.

You are doing your checks at the beginning of the loop:

```
        has_C = "COL_C" in headers
        has_D = "COL_D" in headers
        has_M = "COL_M" in headers
        has_N = "COL_N" in headers
```

Inside the loop, you are not doing unnecessary checks, you are just checking the result of something you already have computed, which is super-fast and really does not need optimization.
You can run a profiler on your code to convince yourself of that:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html

If you are looking for readability, you may want to:

- put the special cases in other methods.
- store the headers in a set to check membership:

```
        headers = f.readline().split(',')
        headers_set = set(headers)
        
        for line in f:
            elements = line.split(',')
            if "COL_C" in headers_set:
                ...  # Special processing related to COL_C
            if "COL_D" in headers_set:
                ...  # Special processing related to COL_D
            if "COL_M" in headers_set:
                ...  # Special processing related to COL_M
            if "COL_N" in headers_set:
                ...  # Special processing related to COL_N
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. I know that checks on pre-computed results are fast, but they are nonetheless time-consuming to some extent, and on a long loop with tens or hundred of those, it may start to have a little impact. Being able to 'factor out' those checks would also improve readability, as you wouldn't need an auxiliary variable for each and every one... The set solution is clean for this example, but won't work with any arbitrary check, which is partially why I wrote the code as I did